# If possible, how to use only cURL with Aspera Shares to upload & download files

Tags: object-storage, ibm-cloud-platform

Our company is signed up to use Aspera Shares, and we're currently accessing that via their Web UI
Looking to automate the uploading and downloading of files.

A few challenges:
We're working on old Macs machines (MacOS Mojave), upgrading not permitted.
We're behind a firewall. We can white-list specific domains/IPs, e.g. to our Aspera server

The existing [API packages](https://www.ibm.com/products/aspera/downloads) require versions of Ruby too new for the old Macs plus other dependencies, and it becomes thorny and clumsy to try to work on figure this out.

So the goal is to approach this strictly using cURL requests if possible.

Is it possible?

Testing using the following links, but so far no luck getting started.

https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/aspera--aspera-shares-2-api/Introduction
https://developer.ibm.com/apis/catalog/aspera--aspera-shares-2-api/Access%20Tokens/
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/aci/3.9.2?topic=acltc-shares-command-reference
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ahts/4.0?topic=aa-transfer-token-creation-node-api-2
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/cli?topic=cloud-object-storage-curl
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage/api-reference?topic=cloud-object-storage-compatibility-api
https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cloud-object-storage?topic=cloud-object-storage-getting-started-cloud-object-storage